# Filling GridView based on DropDownList selected date value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

I am working a asp.net c# code in order to fill Gridview using sql query and dropdownlist.
the scenario is :

1. if dropdownlist selected value is empty then select all from database (select * from table) and fill GridView. That's work perfectly in the visual studio 2008 as well as in the server machine.
2. if dropdownlist selected value is a date (this date was selected from the database so it should match one of the column value in the database) then select * from table where date = dropdownlist.selected value. This one is working if i run it using Visual Studio 2008 but give either an empty Grid for some value or an error which said

> the conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

```
//Page Load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Condtion = "";
        this.BindGrid(Condtion);
    }
}


//Fill Grid View
private void BindGrid( String Condtion )
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ICIRDATAConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {

        String Qsql = "Select * from WeeklyReportView " + Condtion + "";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Qsql))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//Drop down List Selected Index Changed
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt;
    if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue!="1")
    {
        dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
        Condtion1 = "wr_week='" + dt + "'";
    }
    Condtion2 = "eng_name='" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "'";
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "1" && DropDownList2.SelectedValue != "1")
    {
        Condtion = "Where " + Condtion1 + " and " + Condtion2;
    }
    else if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue != "1" && DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        Condtion = "Where " + Condtion2;
    }
    else if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "1" && DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "1")
    {
        Condtion = "Where " + Condtion1;
    }
    else
    {
        Condtion = "";
    }
    this.BindGrid(Condtion);
}
```

Any one can help?

Comment: give us an example for which values are giving this error

Comment: wr_week is which type of field ?

Comment: wr_week is SQL Server DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either pass a date or pass a param type of datetime. You cant put a dateime object into a string and send it to sql server.

Change this line:

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
    Condtion1 = "wr_week='" + dt + "'";
```

To:

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
var datestring = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Condtion1 = "wr_week=convert(datetime, '"+ datestring  +"', 121)";
```

Comment: Sorry Schadensbegrenzer but your solution didn't work i still have the same problem

Comment: @Ayoub I dont know what collation your db is running in, so I updated my answer accordingly. Can you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select * from table where date='"+DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString()+"';
```

Comment: i've tried and i still  have the same problem on the server

Comment: Am working with SQL Server 2005 and i've tried many format but it still work if i run it from Visual Studio 2008 and throw error if I run it in the server machine.

Comment: could you please reformat your answer with appropriate styles (eg code)?

Comment: this is a storde date value : 05/03/2014 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
     dt = DateTime.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
     string ouputDate = dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     Condtion1 = "wr_week='" + ouputDate + "'";
```

Comment: @Ayoub now try this way

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your contribution, i've find the solution, in fact there was incompatibility between the SQL Server installed in my machine, and the one installed in the server machine, the problem was that my sql server has "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" as date format however the server machine sql server have "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm".
thanks once again.

Comment: That's what I told you in my answer :-). The conversion to value "121" will definitely do the trick. Check this link for more mssql datetime conversion options: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp